# Return TEntity in Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>>

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees, generic-programming, func

I have a method which passing an optional/default parameter in Expression Tree like below:

```
Task<TResult> GetSingleAsync<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector = null);
```

What I'm supposed to do is, check when calling above method with ignoring the `selector` parameter, assign `TResult` as `TEntity` to selector inside my method, basically something like `selector = (TEntity) => TEntity`, so I am trying with below implementation

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
     private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _collection;

     public async Task<TResult> GetSingleAsync<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector = null)
     {
          IQueryable<TEntity> query = this._collection;

          if (selector == null) selector = (entity) => default(TResult);

          return await query.Select(selector).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
     }
}
```

when I call the function like `GetSingleAsync<User>()` which ignore the default parameter `selector`, However, the `selector = x => default(TResult)` shows selector as **null**, Is there any way to return the `TEntity` as `TResult` when assign value to the `selector`? I've tried all ways like below but failed as well

```
// error: cannot implicitly convert type 'TEntity' to 'TResult'
if (selector == null) selector = x => x;
if (selector == null) selector = x => TEntity;
if (selector == null) selector = x => (default)TEntity;
if (selector == null) selector = x => (TResult)x;
if (selector == null) selector = x => x as TResult;
```

Comment: the default of a reference type is null, so that is consistent, also this seem fishy, how can you ahve this `GetSingleAsync<TResult>` with just one generic parameter if you have this `Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector = null`, it wouldn't compile

Comment: You could try to cast the incoming `TEntity` to a `TResult` like `x => (TResult) x` or `x => x as TResult` depending on the use-case

Comment: Please paste your real code

Comment: @TheGeneral, Hi, sorry if it gets confused, the `TEntity` is another generic type which I've passed in my class definition, I've pasted my implementation code where you would find what would be `TEntity` here in this method. Thank you!

Comment: @ZachWoods, thank you for your suggestion, I've tried that but it didn't work, I assume it's because TEntity and TResult are both generic type for class which doesn't have a class type constraint.

Comment: Yeah if adding a type constraint isn't allowed then that will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a few options here depending on what your requirements are.

- You could try casting the incoming `TEntity` to a `TResult`. This would require a type constraint on `TResult` and a kinda messy one at that.
- You could check to see if `TEntity` is of the type `TResult` and if it is, you return the casted type. Otherwise return the default `TResult`. This one wouldn't require the type constraint and I think that might be the best you could get without the constraint.
- You could ditch the default parameter value all together and overload the function. Personally, I think this would be your best bet.

Here's examples of the options I listed above:

**Option 1:** Casting with type constraint.

```cs
public async Task<TResult> GetSingleAsync<TResult, TNewEntity>(Expression<Func<TNewEntity, TResult>> selector = null)
where TNewEntity: TEntity, TResult
{
   IQueryable<TNewEntity> query = this._collection;

   if (selector == null) selector = entity => (TResult) entity;

   return await query.Select(selector).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Here you see the ugly type constraint that I was talking about. You have to introduce a new type in order to enforce that your class constraint is of type `TResult`.

**Option 2:** Type check and cast.

```cs
public async Task<TResult> GetSingleAsync<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector = null)
{
    IQueryable<TNewEntity> query = this._collection;

    // I would use pattern matching here if I could, but unfortunately it looks like
    // expression trees cannot have pattern matching so we have to box then cast.
    if (selector == null) selector = entity =>  entity is TResult ? (TResult)(object) entity : default(TResult);


    return await query.Select(selector).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

With this, it will attempt to cast the entity to the correct type but if it can't it will return the default for `TResult` which will be `null` if its a reference type. This will still incur the same problem you were having before, but, in the cases where the cast succeeds, it could be what you want.

**Option 3:** Overload the method.

```cs
// New method with no selector. Notice the return type is now TEntity
public async Task<TEntity> GetSingleAsync(){
    return GetSingleAsync(x => x); // This now works because TResult is TEntity.
}

// Original method, but now it requires the selector
public async Task<TResult> GetSingleAsync<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector)
{
    IQueryable<TNewEntity> query = this._collection;
    return await query.Select(selector).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Personally, this seems like the option that you are wanting and the one that I would use.  It essentially has the same functionality as the default parameter but now requires that, if the selector is not provided, the query will return `TEntity`. However, I don't know all the constraints of your problem or if the default parameter is required.

**Note:** this is similar to what LINQ does with optional selectors. Here's the source for a few of the `ToDictionary` extensions:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
    return ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TSource>(source, keySelector, IdentityFunction<TSource>.Instance, comparer);
}

public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) {
    return ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(source, keySelector, elementSelector, null);
}
```

Notice how they're passing in the identity function for the `elementSelector` and every `TElement` is essentially just replaced by `TSource` in the first method.

**Conclusion:**

There may be other options that aren't listed here but these are the best ones that I could come up with. I tested to see if these would compile, but have not ran any of them.

Comment: thank you so much for providing multiply thoughts, I've tried with Option 2 and Option 3 and they are both working great! Personally I'd prefer your option 3 which is using the overload with optional selector. I really appreciate your knowledge sharing with LINQ implementation here as well!